# Calculus of variation - how to make a function stationary?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I just started learning about the calculus of variations and the following question arose to me:

Given some functional $J[y]$, there exists the notation of a directional derivative defined as
$$
\frac{d}{dy}J[y] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{J[y+\epsilon h] - J[y]}{\epsilon}
\quad\quad \quad(1)
$$
which denotes the derivative of $J[y]$ in the direction of the function $h$ (for simplicity let's don't further examine the particularities of the function space at consideration). Now, if we wanted to find a function that makes  the functional $J[y]$ stationary one would similarly to the function-case take the derivative and set it to zero. However, this seems like a very complicated task in this case since there is no particular function with respect to which we could take the derivative which is why one considers a different approach where we assume $\phi$ to be the function which makes $J[y]$ stationary and then consider a

small variation $J[\phi + \epsilon h] $ and now want compute $\left[\dfrac{d}{d\epsilon}J[\phi + \epsilon h]\right]_0$ which is a simpler task because one now has to deal with an

ordinary derivative instead of a directional $(1)$. Am I on the correct path of understanding this or did I misunderstand something? If the latter holds, I would appreciate it if someone could maybe clarify those points for me.

Comment: Yes, that’s the idea: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations

Comment: Well, technically in the case of calculus, you still have the think of $x_0$ as a starting point at which one takes the derivative. And one finds the starting point at which that derivative in all directions is $0$, which in this case is like finding a $\phi$. Picking some particular $h$, while analogous to a directional derivative, is the step that allows the computation to be simplified to be like a normal derivative. But besides that, this is the general idea.

Comment: The idea is to write the directional derivative  $J'(y;h)$ as $(something) \cdot h$. Then  find $y$ that $something$ is zero.

Comment: @daw could you maybe elaborate on this, because it seems that my understanding is wrong then?